# Newbie: Ruby on rails. Error message on rails installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am trying to get the ruby on rails software on my computer(windows). But i have been getting this result when I input

```
gem install rails -v 4.2.3
```

in command prompt.

```
Error: could not find valid gem rails (=4.2.3)
here is why
Unable to download data from https://ruby_gems.org/- SSL_connect returned=1 errno=1 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (htpps://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

How do I proceed so I can start using my ruby on rails to learn more?
Thanks

Comment: Googling that SSL error turns up a ton of webpages which deal with how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you followed some [instructions like this one](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/installing-rails-5-windows) that uses the ruby installer to install Ruby and the needed dependencies.

Awhile ago I had an issue similar to this when I was behind a proxy trying to install a new gem. After googling I found I had to specify the source and proxy flags in the command to install the new gem.

```
gem install rails --source http://www.rubygems.org --http-proxy http://user:password@proxyip:port
```

But change the source as appropriate and remove the proxy flag if you're not behind one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses guys. But I needed a very basic answer since i am v v v new to this.
For anyone facing the same problem, i found an answer that worked and it just involved me writing this command in command prompt and it did the trick. will get to understanding how this all works as time goes on

https://github.com/jhu-ep-coursera/fullstack-course1-module1/wiki#q-what-to-do-when-rails-fails-to-update

```
gem source -r https://rubygems.org/
gem source -a http://rubygems.org/
gem update --system

gem install rails -v 4.2.3
```

Hope this helps other newbies.

Comment: These commands do the following: 1) remove the source url, 2) add a source url, 3) update the rubygems software.